# Override getResourceAsStream() in android

Tags: java, android

I am looking for a way to override Class.getResourceAsStream(String path) calls in an android project of mine, the project is a J2ME to Android code bridge that has to enable code porting without any changes, so if the native j2me code was calling getResourceAsStream(String path) i need to intercept the call and modify the path to append the proper android folder structure.

Any ideas how this can be implemented?

Comment: Maybe use your own ClassLoader, if Android permits it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the port is going to be more difficult than it sounds, `getResourceAsStream()` being an irrelevant part of the problem. Maybe a simpler strategy could be extracting a library from your existing application and use that library in the ported app.

Anyway, regarding the original question. `Class.getResourceAsStream` delegates to the loading `ClassLoader`, so if you write your own `ClassLoader` you may be able to adjust the path.

Using your own `ClassLoader` means that your application will have two class hierarchies, and this in turn will make them unable to communicate without relying on some API type loaded by a shared loader. I never tried this on Android, but as a thinking exercise you should have your APIs loaded by the Android system, and set the main application loader as the parent for your own (this is what happens in the Servlet world), and finally use your own to load classes that need the path adjustments (obviously your loader won't delegate the loading of resources to its parent withou adjust paths as needed)